# Error: value of <"rect"> = "NaN", Error:Value of <"text"> = "Nan"

Tags: javascript, d3.js

So I am following along on this tutorial for D3JS, I have used javascript some in the past but I really wanted to broaden my horizons and learn how to make these really awesome data driven websites. Plus I am currently working in a place that will in the future require the DDD model and I want to be up to speed when that comes about. However while following this tutorial I get this crazy error

```
Error: value of <"rect"> = "NaN", Error:Value of <"text"> = "Nan"
```

in my inspect console and nothing renders on the page (obviously because it isn't properly getting the data that it needs to display anything), I have tried removing the type function and using the parseInt on the return values in text and rect, as well as leaving the type function and just parsing that value and returning it but nothing seems to be working. I am using a tsv to get the data from and have done everything that the tutorial said to do. Just for giggles I thought hmmm, I have an error, let me try their code. So I copy pasted their code into my code block (not just the pieces that were throwing the error but the entire thing!!!), and got the same error that mine got... hahahahaha now I just want to know what is going on so that I can fix it and move forward with my bar graph extravaganza. any thoughts???

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Stacked Bar Graph</title>
 <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>

<div class="chart">
<script>        
    d3.tsv("data.tsv", type, function(data) {           
        var width = 420, 
            barHeight = 20;         
        var x = d3.scale.linear()
            .range([ 0, width ])
            .domain([ 0, d3.max(data, function(d) {
            return d.value;
        }) ]);
        var chart = d3.select(".chart")
            .append("svg")
            .attr("width", width)
            .attr("height", barHeight * data.length);
        var bar = chart.selectAll("g")
            .data(data)
            .enter()
            .append("g")
                .attr("transform", function(d, i) {
                    return "translate(0," + i * barHeight + ")";
                });
        bar.append("rect").attr("width", function(d) {
            return x(d.value);
        }).attr("height", barHeight - 1).attr("fill", "steelblue");

        bar.append("text").attr("x", function(d) {
            return x(d.value) - 3;
        }).attr("y", barHeight / 2).attr("dy", ".35em").attr("fill",
                "white").attr("font", "10px san-serif").attr("text-anchor",
                "end").text(function(d) {
            return d.value;
        });
    });     
    function type(d) {
        d.value = +d.value;
        return d;
    }
</script>
</div>
```

data.tsv file

```
name    value
Locke   4
Reyes   8
Ford    15
Jarrah  16
Shepard 23
Kwon    42
```

Comment: Try to print the data to the console to see if anything is being returned.

Comment: Please show a sample from data.tsv.

Comment: @SlipperyPete The question has been updated with the data.tsv file sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: Thanks @RichardDavy, I don't know if it's an artifact from posting on the site, but I had to edit the TSV separators to be tabs instead of spaces.  Then your code worked.  See answer below.

Comment: @SlipperyPete okay, I have to ask what program it is that you are editing the tsv file with, I am using notepad++ and I am getting the same result with the tabs, what if I switched to csv for simplicity

Comment: okay so it is definitely the tabbing issue, I am not really sure how to fix it though, I changed the file to a csv and it worked fine, the notepad++ editor I am using likes to arrange everything into predefined columns and holds the tab to that, exactly how many spaces does a tsv expect for a tab, 4 or 5?

Comment: I don't use Notepad++, I am using Visual Studio.  Plain old Notepad should work too.  The TSV expects tabs, not spaces.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the values in the TSV are separated by tabs, not spaces.